# AWS S3 Files from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

```
 from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

 AWS_KEY = 'abc'
 AWS_SECRET = 'xyz'

 print AWS_KEY
 print AWS_SECRET

 aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)

 print aws_connection


 #Create the bucket in a specific region.

 bucket = aws_connection.create_bucket('mybucket0005',location='us-west-2')
```

This code i am running for creating bucket;but getting below Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-63-f14efbf83dc6>", line 16, in <module>
bucket = aws_connection.create_bucket('mybucket0005',location='us-west-2')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 625, in create_bucket
response.status, response.reason, body)

S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you     provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>abc</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>930E9DC30F239D11</RequestId><HostId>xlaLEeS7C4KYgLOKOShF9uGhLgM+4OdFYiLGn7F5JvKty38kAir5vSNSDH7q5TWFPO/6BEjeHaA=</HostId></Error>
```

I want to Access AWS S3 Files from Python.Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The message in this case is quite explicit

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

There is no *abc* key. If you have an AWS account, go to the IAM console and take the key from there: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

Even better create a new user that will only be used for CLI. You need to make sure this user will have rights on your s3 bucket (if the goal is to manage that). Once you have the user created, [create security credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-iam-create-creds.html) that you can use from your script.

Another point: DO NOT EXPOSE YOUR AWS KEY directly in your script. 
Check the [Boto doc](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) on how to manage your credentials and use them from your script.

Comment: access_key = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
secret_key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
I am using this one only..still getting same error.

Comment: honestly _EXAMPLE_ in your access_key, I am not saying it can not happen but I really doubt, dont take it from somewhere on the net, take it from your account

Comment: Now i am using correct access key from my account only.
now its showing this error:(while creating bucket)
  raise ex

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: humm .. can you try `bucket = aws_connection.create_bucket('mybucket0005', Location.USWest2)` I would also recommend you switch to latest boto3 (rather than boto v2)

Comment: Now i am able to create bucket..i want to read CSV file now
i am using this code :
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
not able to read.

Comment: I think you should close your question with the connection, accept if it solved your pbm and open a new question with the new error you have

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your AWS keys are correct? You can use [Commandeer App](https://getcommandeer.com) to Test it out from the new/existing account screen.
[image: Testing your AWS credentials from Commandeer App]